# what is the right way to ues svg_to_paint?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, svg

I am fllowing guide in " [https://pub.dev/packages/svg_to_paint"](https://pub.dev/packages/svg_to_paint%22) ,

run `$ flutter pub global activate svg_to_paint` in gitbash, twice.
And get:
`Package svg_to_paint is currently active at version 1.0.10. Resolving dependencies... The package svg_to_paint is already activated at newest available version. To recompile executables, first run`flutter pub global deactivate svg_to_paint`. Activated svg_to_paint 1.0.10.` 
but next :
$svg_to_paint
`bash: svg_to_paint: command not found`
$flutter svg_to_paint
`
Could not find a command named "svg_to_paint".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.
`
I just have now idea ,why and what should to do .

just have no idea . I try run the command in Android Studio too. but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try with flutter pub run svg_to_paint